# Nav Links working but not passing test in FreeCodeCamp Challenge: Product Landing Page

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning to code using freecodecamp. However, I am stuck on the "create a product landing page" challenge.

The challenge asks for the following:

> User Story #5: When I click a .nav-linkbutton in the nav element, I am >taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.

To me it looks like my code fulfills this brief (it certainly seems to work), but for some reason it isn't passing the tests. I would be very grateful for any advice:

Here is the relevant code (please let me know if you need to see the whole page).

```
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
<ul>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#home">Home</>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#about">About</a>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#news">News</a>
</ul>
</nav>


<div id="home">
</div>
<div id="about">
<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cta5-rpoeB4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="news">
</div>
```

When I run tests I get the following error:

> 5. When I click a .nav-link button in the nav element, I am taken to the corresponding section of the landing page.'
>      Each .nav-link element should have an href attribute : expected false to >equal true
>      AssertionError: Each .nav-link element should have an href attribute : >expected false to equal true

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: your links might work, even the one that was not closed properly, because most modern browsers will correct the html tag errors, but didn't pass the test because the tags were not all closed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are clicking on the anchor (a) element, not the li element. Can you try giving the  tag the nav-link class?

Another thing they specifically mention button here. You don't have any  elements. If you create a button with .nav-link and a href attribute will that make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your list item and at tags needs the proper html tag encapsulation.  I like to type my html like a paragraph with my encapsulations so I can keep track of closing tags

```
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
             <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
             <a href="#news">News</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li ><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li ><a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

exitos amigo!!

Comment: Please provide a solution description